# Arduino does not execute command from serial and slow to execute commands

Tags: arduino, rgb, arduino-uno, led, arduino-ide

I have not been on stack for a while so I do apolagize for that, the community has always helped me and really want to thank all for that first of all.

I am having a problem with an arduino project I am trying to make the arduino make rgb light go on an off in different color upon user input. This sounds basic but unfortunately the arduino does not do it in some situations or is really slow to receive inputs from the user.

I can't figure out if it's a problem with the code or the arduino it self.

Here is the bit of code I think it's the problem, and when trying this menu commands are executed once but then does not drop the loop and throw me back to main menu.

Mind that the code is really really long so this is only a bit of it, for the complete code look below.

(FIY ARDUINO UNO R3 ATMEGA 328)

```
//Party  
  if(mode == "Party" || mode == "party" || mode == "Party mode" || mode == "party mode" || mode == "Party Mode" || mode == "party Mode" || mode == "c"){
    Serial.println("Party mode");
    Serial.println("For selecting another mode and go back please type back");
  int y;

  int w;
  Serial.println("How many times? note: 1 time = 20 seconds");
while(Serial.available()==0){
  direct = Serial.readString();

  if(direct == "Back" || direct == "back" ){
    break;
  }

  y = 0;
  w = Serial.parseInt();

 if(y <= w){ 

for(int i = 0; i < w; i = i+1){
  Serial.println("Initializing");
  Serial.println(w);

  for(int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue <= 250; fadeValue +=50){
   analogWrite(ledRR1, fadeValue);
   analogWrite(ledBR1, fadeValue);
   delay(500);
   analogWrite(ledGR1, fadeValue);
   analogWrite(ledGL1,fadeValue);
   analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
   analogWrite(ledRR1,0);
   analogWrite(ledGL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBL2,0); 
   analogWrite(ledGR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBR2,0);


    delay(500);
  }
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGR2, 250);
     analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);
     analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
     analogWrite(ledRL1,0);
   analogWrite(ledGL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBL2,0); 
   analogWrite(ledGR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBR2,0);
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(ledBR1, 250); 
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
  delay(500);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 150);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 50);
  delay(1000);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
  delay(500);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 150);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 50);
  delay(500);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
  delay(1000);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 150);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 50);
  delay(2000);

  analogWrite(ledGL1,250);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  delay(1000);
    analogWrite(ledGL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  delay(500);
    analogWrite(ledRR1,250);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
  delay(1000);
    analogWrite(ledRR1,0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
  delay(500);
    analogWrite(ledGL1,250);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBR1,250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1,250);
  delay(2000);
    analogWrite(ledGL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  delay(1000);

    analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledGL2,0);
  analogWrite(ledRL2,0);
  analogWrite(ledBL2,0); 
  analogWrite(ledGR2,0);
  analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
  analogWrite(ledBR2,0);

  y = y +1;
}
 }
 else if(y >= w){
   Serial.println("Please type main to go back to main menu or select another value");
   break;
 }
}

  }
```

As mentioned the code is really really long so here is all the code:

```
//List of pins and corresponding colors

//RIGHT SIDE
//Red1 5
//Green1 3
//Blue1 6

//Red4 A4
//Green4 A3
//Blue4 A5


////////////////////////////////////////////


//Left Side
//Red2 9
//Green2 11
//Blue2 10

//Red3 A1
//Green3 A0
//Blue3 A2


//Right Side
int ledRR1 = 5;
int ledGR1 = 3;
int ledBR1 = 6;

int ledRR2 = A4;
int ledGR2 = A3;
int ledBR2 = A5;

///////////////////

//Left Side
int ledRL1 = 9;
int ledGL1 = 11;
int ledBL1 = 10;

int ledRL2 = A1;
int ledGL2 = A0;
int ledBL2 = A2;

//////////////////


//Strings

String mode;
String node;
String moving;
String direct;
int x;



void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

//PinMode

pinMode(ledRR1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledGR1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledBR1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledRR2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledGR2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledBR2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledRL1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledGL1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledBL1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledRL2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledGL2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledBL2, OUTPUT);

//START IN THIS STATE:

//Right
analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);

analogWrite(ledRR2, 0);
analogWrite(ledGR2, 0);
analogWrite(ledBR2, 0);

//Left
analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);

analogWrite(ledRL2, 0);
analogWrite(ledGL2, 0);
analogWrite(ledBL2, 0);

x = 0;


}

void loop(){

Serial.println("Main menu");

 while(Serial.available()==0){

  mode = Serial.readString();
  node = Serial.readString();
  moving = Serial.readString();
  Serial.setTimeout(50);


  while( x <= 0){

  Serial.println("Welcome to Andy Mood'O Matic light machine");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Please select the mode according to your mood");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Commands and available modes");
  Serial.println("Commands: Main Menu or just main");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Please type modes to see the available modes");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("SOMETIMES THE ARDUINO IS SLOW AND YOU HAVE TO INPUT THE COMMAND TWICE!");
  x = x+1;
  }

  if(node == "modes" || node == "Modes"){
    Serial.println("Available modes, NOTE: YOU CAN USE SIMPLE COMMANDS!");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Relax /SIMPLE COMMAND: a");
      Serial.println("   Automated Relax mode");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Intimate /SIMPLE COMMAND: b");
      Serial.println("  Automated intimate mode");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Party mode or Party /SIMPLE COMMAND: c");
      Serial.println("  This is user controlled, set the amount of time you want the lights to go for");
      Serial.println("  Please check description in party mode to see available options");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Night /SIMPLE COMMAND: d");
      Serial.println("  Automated night mode");
      Serial.println("  User controlled night mode, set how dim the lights should be and time");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Off /SIMPLE COMMAND o");
      Serial.println("   Turns everything off");


  }

  if(moving == "Main Menu" || moving == "main menu" || moving == "Main menu" || moving == "main Menu" || moving == "main menu" || moving == "main" || moving == "Main"){
    //This is to go back to main main, for each stop loop you have to add this to repeat the println
  x = x-1;
  }




//Relax
  if(mode == "Relax" || mode == "relax" || mode == "a" ){
    Serial.println("This is automatic relax mode");

   for(int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue <= 250; fadeValue +=10){

    analogWrite(ledGR1,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGL1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledGR2, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGL2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBR2,fadeValue); 
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue); 

    delay(60000);
  }


  for (int fadeValue = 250; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -= 10){
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledGR2,fadeValue); 
    analogWrite(ledGL2, fadeValue); 
    analogWrite(ledGR1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGL1,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue); 
    analogWrite(ledBR2,fadeValue); 

    // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
    delay(60000);
  }



   for(int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue <= 250; fadeValue +=10){

    analogWrite(ledGR2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGL2, 0); 
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBR2,fadeValue); 
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue); 

    delay(60000);
  }


  for (int fadeValue = 250; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -= 10){
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledGR2,fadeValue); 
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 0); 
    analogWrite(ledGR2, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGL2, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue); 
    analogWrite(ledBR2,fadeValue); 

    // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
    delay(60000);
  }


  analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGR1,0);
  analogWrite(ledGR2,0);
  analogWrite(ledGL2,0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBL2,0); 
  analogWrite(ledBR2,0); 
}



//Off 
  if(mode == "Off" || mode == "o" || mode == "off"){
    Serial.println("Everything off");

      analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);

      analogWrite(ledRR2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGR2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBR2, 0);


      analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);

      analogWrite(ledRL2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGL2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBL2, 0); 

  }


//Intimate  
  if(mode == "intimate" || mode == "Intimate" || mode == "b"){
    Serial.println("Automatic Intimate mode");
    for(int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue <= 150; fadeValue +=50){

    analogWrite(ledRR1,250);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGR1,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRR2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBR2,fadeValue);

    delay(60000);
  }

  for (int fadeValue = 250; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -= 50){
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledRR1,250);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGR1,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL2, 250);
    analogWrite(ledRR2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBR2,150);

    // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
    delay(60000);
  }

      for (int fadeValue = 250; fadeValue >= 150; fadeValue -= 50){
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, 0);
    analogWrite(ledGR1,0);
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
    analogWrite(ledBR2, 150);
    delay(60000);
      }

    for (int fadeValue = 150; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -= 50){
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledRR1,250);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, 0);
    analogWrite(ledGR1,0);
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
    analogWrite(ledBR2,fadeValue);
    delay(60000);
    }

  for (int fadeValue = 250; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -= 50){
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledRR1,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, 0);
    analogWrite(ledGR1,0);
    analogWrite(ledBL2,0);
    analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
    analogWrite(ledBR2,0);

    // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
    delay(60000);
  }

  for(int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue <= 150; fadeValue +=50){

    analogWrite(ledRR1,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBL2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRR2,fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBR2,fadeValue);

    delay(60000);
  }
    for(int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue <= 250; fadeValue +=50){

    analogWrite(ledRR1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 150);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 150);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBL2, 150);
    analogWrite(ledRR2, fadeValue);
    analogWrite(ledBR2, 150);

    delay(60000);
  }
    analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBL1, 150);
    analogWrite(ledBR1, 150);
    analogWrite(ledRL2, 0);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBL2, 150);
    analogWrite(ledRR2, 0);
    analogWrite(ledBR2, 150);

 }


//Party  
  if(mode == "Party" || mode == "party" || mode == "Party mode" || mode == "party mode" || mode == "Party Mode" || mode == "party Mode" || mode == "c"){
    Serial.println("Party mode");
    Serial.println("For selecting another mode and go back please type back");
  int y;

  int w;
  Serial.println("How many times? note: 1 time = 20 seconds");
while(Serial.available()==0){
  direct = Serial.readString();

  if(direct == "Back" || direct == "back" ){
    break;
  }

  y = 0;
  w = Serial.parseInt();

 if(y <= w){ 

for(int i = 0; i < w; i = i+1){
  Serial.println("Initializing");
  Serial.println(w);

  for(int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue <= 250; fadeValue +=50){
   analogWrite(ledRR1, fadeValue);
   analogWrite(ledBR1, fadeValue);
   delay(500);
   analogWrite(ledGR1, fadeValue);
   analogWrite(ledGL1,fadeValue);
   analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
   analogWrite(ledRR1,0);
   analogWrite(ledGL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBL2,0); 
   analogWrite(ledGR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBR2,0);


    delay(500);
  }
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGR2, 250);
     analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);
     analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
     analogWrite(ledRL1,0);
   analogWrite(ledGL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRL2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBL2,0); 
   analogWrite(ledGR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
   analogWrite(ledBR2,0);
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(ledBR1, 250); 
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
  delay(500);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 150);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 50);
  delay(1000);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
  delay(500);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 150);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 50);
  delay(500);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
  delay(1000);
    analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledGL1, 150);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 50);
  delay(2000);

  analogWrite(ledGL1,250);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  delay(1000);
    analogWrite(ledGL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  delay(500);
    analogWrite(ledRR1,250);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
  delay(1000);
    analogWrite(ledRR1,0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
  delay(500);
    analogWrite(ledGL1,250);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
  analogWrite(ledBR1,250);
  analogWrite(ledBL1,250);
  delay(2000);
    analogWrite(ledGL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  delay(1000);

    analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledGL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);
  analogWrite(ledRL1,0);
  analogWrite(ledGL2,0);
  analogWrite(ledRL2,0);
  analogWrite(ledBL2,0); 
  analogWrite(ledGR2,0);
  analogWrite(ledRR2,0);
  analogWrite(ledBR2,0);

  y = y +1;
}
 }
 else if(y >= w){
   Serial.println("Please type main to go back to main menu or select another value");
   break;
 }
}

  }


//Night  
  if(mode == "Night" || mode == "night" || mode == "d"){
    Serial.println("Automatic night mode");

      analogWrite(ledRR1, 250);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, 250);
      analogWrite(ledBR1, 250);

      analogWrite(ledRR2, 250);
      analogWrite(ledGR2, 250);
      analogWrite(ledBR2, 250);


      analogWrite(ledRL1, 250);
      analogWrite(ledGL1, 250);
      analogWrite(ledBL1, 250);

      analogWrite(ledRL2, 250);
      analogWrite(ledGL2, 250);
      analogWrite(ledBL2, 250); 
      delay(3600000);


  for(int fadeValue = 250; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -=50){

     analogWrite(ledRR1, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledBR1, fadeValue);

      analogWrite(ledRR2, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledGR2, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledBR2, fadeValue);


      analogWrite(ledRL1, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledGL1, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledBL1, fadeValue);

      analogWrite(ledRL2, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledGL2, fadeValue);
      analogWrite(ledBL2, fadeValue);

      delay(120000);
     Serial.println("Good Night");


  }
        analogWrite(ledRR1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGR1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBR1, 0);

      analogWrite(ledRR2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGR2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBR2, 0);


      analogWrite(ledRL1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGL1, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBL1, 0);

      analogWrite(ledRL2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledGL2, 0);
      analogWrite(ledBL2, 0); 
   break;   
  }

}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Come on seriously under-vote me? For what reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not surprised your code is extremely slow (to usart commands). So many delays in there. You need short delays in for each passing through loop. And for example state machine if you want fast responses.

Some gotchas:

- Awful formatting
- The `while (Serial.available() == 0)` is pretty weird condition. If there are data available, it'll always skip whole loop.
- Comments:

  ```
      // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
      delay(60000);
  ```

  It is not 30ms but 60000ms (60s)
- A lot of constant strings for Serial.print. You can use F("some flash string") helper to store these strings only in Flash memory (otherwise it must be copies into the RAM and displayed from it)

And if you're checking and processing incomming commands once in "hour" (figuratively speaking), it's pretty difficult to be "fast".

Something like this can be used (it is just brief sketch):

```
// prototypes:
uint32_t  main_menu_fsm(byte & state);
uint32_t  mode_menu_fsm(byte & state);
uint32_t   off_mode_fsm(byte & state);
uint32_t relax_mode_fsm(byte & state);

// global variables for FSM
byte                         glob_state = 0;
uint32_t                     next_check = 0;
uint32_t (*state_machine)(byte & state) = &main_menu_fsm;

#define SET_FSM(fsm) Serial.println("Setting: " #fsm); glob_state=0; next_check=0; state_machine = &fsm


// global variables for Serial processing
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data

// RGBLed class
template <byte PinR, byte PinG, byte PinB>
class RGBLed {
  public:
    void begin(byte r = 0, byte g = 0, byte b = 0) {
      pinMode(PinR, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(PinG, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(PinB, OUTPUT);
      set(r,g,b);
    }

    void set(byte r = 0, byte g = 0, byte b = 0) {
      analogWrite(PinR, r);
      analogWrite(PinG, g);
      analogWrite(PinB, b);
    }
};

RGBLed<9,10,11>  Led1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Led1.begin(10,10,10);
  inputString.reserve(50); // should be enough for all commands


}

void loop() {
  uint32_t curr = millis();
  if (curr > next_check) {
    next_check = curr + state_machine(glob_state);
/*  // debug:
    Serial.print(curr);
    Serial.print(" "); 
    Serial.print(next_check);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(glob_state);
*/
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char ch = (char)Serial.read();
    if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n') {
      if (inputString.length()>0) {
        inputString.toLowerCase();
        Serial.println(inputString);

        if (inputString.length()==1) {
          switch (inputString[0]) {
            case 'a': SET_FSM(relax_mode_fsm); break;
            case 'o': SET_FSM(off_mode_fsm);   break;
          }
        } else if (inputString.startsWith("main")) {
          SET_FSM(main_menu_fsm);
        } else if (inputString.startsWith("mode")) {
          SET_FSM(mode_menu_fsm);
        }
        inputString = ""; // reset string
        break; // process command - interrupt processing
      }
    } else {
      inputString += ch;
    }
  }
}

uint32_t  main_menu_fsm(byte & state) {
  if (state == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Welcome to Andy Mood'O Matic light machine"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Please select the mode according to your mood"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Commands and available modes"));
    Serial.println(F("Commands: Main Menu or just main"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Please type modes to see the available modes"));

    ++state;
  }
  return 5000UL;
}

uint32_t  mode_menu_fsm(byte & state) {
  if (state == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Available modes, NOTE: YOU CAN USE SIMPLE COMMANDS!"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Relax or a [works only 'a' and just brief implementation]"));
      Serial.println(F("   Automated Relax mode"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Intimate or b [not implemented]"));
      Serial.println(F("  Automated intimate mode"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Party mode or Party or c [not implemented]"));
      Serial.println(F("  This is user controlled, set the amount of time you want the lights to go for"));
      Serial.println(F("  Please check description in party mode to see available options"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Night or d"));
      Serial.println(F("  Automated night mode [not implemented]"));
      Serial.println(F("  User controlled night mode, set how dim the lights should be and time"));
    Serial.println(F(""));
    Serial.println(F("Off or o [works only 'o']"));
      Serial.println(F("   Turns everything off"));

    ++state;
  }
  return 5000UL;
}

uint32_t   off_mode_fsm(byte & state) {
  if (state == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Entering Off Mode"));
    Led1.set(0,0,0);
    ++state;
  }
  return 5000UL;
}

uint32_t relax_mode_fsm(byte & state) {
  if (state == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Entering Off Mode"));
  }

  if (++state == 8) state = 1;

  Led1.set((1 & state) * 255, (1 & (state >> 1)) * 128, (1 & (state >> 2)) * 128);

  return 2000UL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it's a Uno R3 ATMEGA 328. Is there a way to make long delays on arduino or it's just the ram that won't handle it?

Comment: How would you make that while loop? I just want it to wait for user input it shouldn't skip the loop

Comment: @IamtheLawTheLaw added brief concept. Parameters for party mode will be little bit harder there.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It worked, although I seriously gonna get some researching into it, because I do recognize some of the arrays, and yes I could have made it into an array, but some of the other stuff like the unsigned integers I really don't know much about it. Thank you though you just opened a hole new door to me!